# Cannot find module - Nuxt 3, TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, tsconfig, nuxt3

When trying to do an import .ts file in 'nuxt.config.ts' using the path '@/' and '~/' I get the error: Cannot find module '~/path', Require stack: - nuxt.config.ts at Module._resolveFilename....

Sample code in the nuxt.config.ts file

```
// this code does not work
import headConfig from '~/config/head/headConfig';
// import headConfig from '@/config/head/headConfig';

// this code work
// import headConfig from './config/head/headConfig';


export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: false },

  app: {
    head: headConfig,
  },
});
```

[Demo on the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-ebgkio?file=config%2Fhead%2FheadConfig.ts,nuxt.config.ts)

Nuxt 3.8.2 | node 18.18.0 | npm 9.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature is currently [not supported](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/20830). So, inside the `nuxt.config.ts` file, you have to use relative or absolute paths for `import`.

Answer (score 0):

In Nuxt.js, the @ alias is set by default to reference the rootDir (project root) directory. If you don't have a src directory and your configuration or files are directly in the root directory or some other directory

@ alias for specific directories like Vue CLI does with src. Instead, you can use relative paths or specify the exact path to import your files according to your project's directory structure.

I hope help you